# Update text & color

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to fill an object and at the same time to update the text of 'clurN' to "Done!!". How do I do this?

```
<p id="clurN">Test</p>
<a class="button" style="background-color: #000;" onClick="clur()"></a>
<script>
function clur() {
var str = "Done!!";
document.getElementById("clurN").innerHTML=result;

var c=document.getElementById("c1Canvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the impression you just slapped together directly the code of some tutorials you've found on the internet. Try seeing what the code does in the examples next time, and then seeing how you'd implement that into your code. Here's the working code for you:

```
<p id="clurN">Test</p>
<a class="button" style="background-color:#000;" onClick="clur()"></a>
<script>
function clur() {
    //Store the element in the variable:
    var paragraph = document.getElementById("clurN");

    //change the element's inner HTML:
    paragraph.innerHTML = "Done!!";

    //and now set its background color style:
    paragraph.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
}
</script>
```

Comment: If this answer was what you were looking for, please mark it as accepted via the checkmark to the left of this question. That will indicate that this question has been answered, so others can see that more easily.